# MikroORM: "must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Tags: nestjs, query-builder, mikro-orm

I have the following query set up using the QueryBuilder:

```
  return this.qb('user')
      .where({ id })
      .leftJoin('user.transactions', 'transactions')
      .leftJoin('user.wallet', 'wallet')
      .leftJoin('user.userLevel', 'userLevel')
      .select([
        'avatarUrl',
        'otpEnabled',
        'userName',
        'profilePrivacy',
        'userType',
        'userLevel.level',
        'loginType',
        'createdAt',
        'wallet.balance',
        this.qb()
          .where({
            transactions: {
              transactionType: {
                name: TransactionTypeName.TipSent,
              },
            },
          })
          .select('sum(transactions.amount)')
          .as('totalTipSent'),
        this.qb()
          .where({
            transactions: {
              transactionType: {
                name: TransactionTypeName.TipReceived,
              },
            },
          })
          .select('sum(transactions.amount)')
          .as('totalTipReceived'),
      ])
      .execute('get');
```

However, I keep on getting `\"user.avatarUrl\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. Is what im trying to do just simply impossible with the queryBuilder?

Comment: What query are you trying to build and what query are you getting? The error is from the DB server, not from the ORM.

Comment: I don't understand your question, the query im trying to build is right there in my question, which is pretty much summing the amount found in the transactions table based on the transactiontype, which is where it goes wrong appearantly.

Comment: You provided a code, I am asking for the exact SQL query you want to generate, not about how you use the QB.

Comment: And more importantly, I am asking what query does your code generate.

Comment: As said above, this is an error from the database level, and I'd expect you won't see such error if you don't use `group by` clause at all - and I don't see that you would be using it.

Comment: I could understand some issues with pagination, but since you are not applying any limit or offset, it shouldn't be used either. If you provide the generated query, I can at least know whether the pagination mechanism takes effect or not.